Why can I access members of a struct defined inside a private section of class in C++?
I'm implementing a tree in C++ using linked lists. I've defined a struct Node within the private section of my GenericTree class, but I can still access its members from the main function, which confuses me.
//

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class GenericTree {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* LEFT;
        Node* RIGHT;

        Node(const T& value) : data(value), LEFT(nullptr), RIGHT(nullptr) {}
    };

    Node* root;
    size_t count;

public:
    GenericTree(const T& value) : root(new Node(value)), count(1) {}

    Node* GetRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    // Additional methods...
};

int main() {
    GenericTree<int> tree(1);
    // This part is where I'm confused
    std::cout << tree.GetRoot()->data;
    // etc.

    return 0;
}

I expected to get an error since Node is defined as a private member of GenericTree, but the code compiles and runs without issues.
Questions:
Why can I access the LEFT and RIGHT members of Node?
What are the implications of having Node defined as private?
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Access (public/private) is a feature of the name. So you cannot use the name Node in main but there is no problem using Node objects or Node pointers.

Making private something that is a part of class interface does not make sense.

Once you return a value, the secret is out! You can use decltype(tree.GetRoot()) to get the return type.

T data;, Node* LEFT;, Node* RIGHT; are public in struct Node.  Regardless of struct Node itself being a private name.  Access specifiers are not transitive.
